# c# Sum values of same interval and date and type from datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

#### Input

I have a `DataTable` with the following structure (with some sample values):

[image: sample input]

#### Output

I want to have a `DataTable` like this which holds the calculation result:

[image: expected output]

#### Transformation logic

- I want to *SUM* the value where `Date`, `Interval` and `Type` are the same.

#### Save logic

1. I want to copy the result to another `DataTable`.
2. I want to save that copy to my main table in SQL server.

#### Considerations / Requirements

- I would like to do this with LINQ.
- I don't want to use a temporary table in SQL server for this.

#### My code (so far)

```cs
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => new
    {
        Date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
        Interval = row.Field<DateTime>("Interval"),
        Type = row.Field<string>("Type")
    })
    .Select(a =>
    {
        var row = a.First();
        row.SetField("Value", a.Sum(r => r.Field<double> "Value")));

        return row;
    });

var resultdt = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Please show your code. That would make it easier to help.

Comment: I dont have something to show. I dont know how to syntax it because I need to group them by interval, date, type and get sum of same interval. Too many parameters that I cant syntax it. I can only syntax on expression with one group by and one simple where, not this. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: I posted some code after reading some other topics about linq.

Comment: @Kate10 What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Use GroubBy(x => Interval.Date  :  The date property truncates the date to the  midnight at the start of a day  and drops the hours, minutes, seconds from the time.

Comment: I have tested the code I managed to write and it looks like it is working so far.  But I only based it in another example so I am not sure it is correct. I am testing it with different types and intervals and dates to see if it is good.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Dummy data for demo purpose
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Type");
            dt.Columns.Add("Date");
            dt.Columns.Add("Inverval");
            dt.Columns.Add("Value");

            dt.Rows.Add("one", "1/1/2020", 0.00, 11);
            dt.Rows.Add("one", "1/1/2020", 0.00, 1);
            dt.Rows.Add("one", "1/1/2020", 0.15, 1);
            dt.Rows.Add("two", "1/1/2020", 0.00, 6);
            dt.Rows.Add("two", "1/1/2020", 0.00, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add("two", "1/1/2020", 0.15, 4);


            var result = from tab in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         group tab by new
                         {
                             Type = tab["Type"],
                             Date = tab["Date"],
                             Inverval = tab["Inverval"]
                         }
                into groupDt
                         select new
                         {
                             Type = groupDt.Key.Type,
                             Date = groupDt.Key.Date,
                             Inverval = groupDt.Key.Inverval,
                             Value= groupDt.Sum((r) => decimal.Parse(r["Value"].ToString()))
                         };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this. I will test it and get back to you.

Comment: How do I copy the result to a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use GroupBy. Try like:

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Interval)
```

Comment: Yes, obviously and not just the Interval.